# JMeter PerfMon Metrics Collector plugin to work with JMX

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I have trouble getting JMeter PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to collect JMX data. I have started the "serverAgent". I have started remote JBoss server with the following parameters, as stated in the plugin homepage https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon :

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4711 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I then configure the JMeter Perf Mon listener to collect data from port "5444", Metric to collect "JMX", and Metric parameter "gc-time". Further in config I have defined JMX connection parameter to "localhost" and port "4711".

When I start JMeter tests the "serverAgent" drops with the following error:

```
 INFO    2013-03-22 16:16:06.682 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: jmx:gc-time   cpu:
ERROR: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: method java.lang.String.isEmpty with signature ()Z     was not found.
*** Problem's technical details go below ***

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: method java.lang.String.isEmpty     with signature ()Z was not found.
   at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.JMXMetric.<init>(JMXMetric.java:35)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.AbstractPerfMonMetric.createMetric(AbstractPerfMonMetric.java:65)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.setUpMetrics(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:138)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:63)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processNextCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:101)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.read(PerfMonWorker.java:210)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processCommands(PerfMonWorker.java:97)
   at kg.apc.perfmon.AgentTool.processParams(AgentTool.java:72)
   at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
   at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:150)
```

If I only collect CPU and Memory then JMeter gets everything fine. It's only when collecting JMX that I get this exception. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The isEmpty() method wasn't added until JDK 1.6.  My guess is that you are using JDK 1.5 or older.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a standalone JMX metrics collector in jmeter plugins (as of version 1.1.2)

Although it is quite new (and likely to be full of bugs, because I wrote it :), maybe you can try that one?